# Is icing a soft tissue injury helpful to recovery?

Tags: medical-science

It seems to be common knowledge that icing an injury, such as a sprain or a bump, is beneficial to treatment. I'd like to focus this question on sprains (with no bone damage). Does it actually help the body heal or is it just to numb the pain?

[Webmd](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/ankle-sprain-treatment-overview) recommends to ice ankle sprains but states "There is not good scientific evidence that ice or contrast baths help, but they are often used."

This [NCBI article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3396304/) states that

> Randomized controlled trials provide insufficient evidence to
>   determine the effectiveness of rest, ice, compression, and elevation
>   (RICE) therapy for acute ankle sprains in adults. Treatment decisions
>   must be made on an individual basis, carefully weighing the relative
>   risks and benefits of each option, and must be based on expert
>   opinions and guidelines. Sufficiently powered, high-quality, and
>   appropriately reported randomized trials of the different elements of
>   RICE therapy for acute ankle sprains are needed.

[This article](http://patient.info/health/ice-and-heat-treatment-for-injuries) points out that icing may cause less pain so the person can do there exercises better

> In the later, or rehabilitation, phase of recovery the aim changes to
>   restoring normal function. At this stage the effects of ice can
>   enhance other treatments, such as exercise, by reducing pain and
>   muscle spasm. This then allows better movement. If you are doing
>   exercises as part of your treatment, it can be useful to apply an ice
>   pack before exercise. This is so that after the ice pack is removed
>   the area will still be a little numb. The exercises can also be done
>   with the ice pack in place. This reduces pain and makes movement
>   around the injury more comfortable.

I'm a bit confused as it seems like icing an injury is so basic it doesn't need a scientific test to prove it's usefulness. For example there isn't a scientific test that proves bandages are useful.